# How to echo an image using PHP

Tags: php

How can I echo an image using PHP?

This is what I have:

```
 echo "<img src="Images/Picture.GIF">";//This should echo my image
```

Comment: You can't use double-quotes inside of double-quotes without escaping them. You need `echo "<img src=\"Images/Picture.GIF\">";`

Comment: Bit more info needed... is "Images/Picture.GIF" a valid path to an image? What server are you using? Unix based server will use case sensitive file names... are you sure its a ".GIF" and not ".gif"

Comment: `echo '<img src="Images/Picture.gif">' `

Comment: `echo "<img src=\"Images/Picture.GIF\">";` should work or you could use single quotes  `echo '<img src="Images/Picture.GIF\">';`

Answer (score 7):

If by "echo" you mean outputting the image in a browser, you need to read it first then send it with `echo`. Something like this should work:

```
$content = file_get_contents('Images/Picture.GIF');
header('Content-Type: image/gif');
echo $content;
```

Comment: why you can simple request Images/Picture.gif directly.

Comment: based on the vague question, this is a valid point... why downvote?

Comment: (Not the down voter) - But based on the code provided, this not what OP is trying to do.

Comment: based on the code provided, the op doesn't know what they are trying to do

Comment: It is valid since it will produce the same output but it is not what OP is trying to do. (Not the down voter)

Comment: down voter because `file_get_contents` return content file in string http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php, `readfile()` in first parameters get filename.... http://php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php

Comment: @Gavin It looks simply like OP got mixed up with `"` and `'`, not knowing you can't do a double `"` like he is.

Comment: @Naumov, you're right, I guess `echo $content;` instead would work. I've updated the answer.

Answer (score 3):

You cant `echo` an image using PHP.

[PHP echo](http://php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php)

> echo — Output one or more strings

`echo` is for strings only. 
However, you can `echo` the image source - `img src=""`
Just make sure you put the picture extension at the end of the file you are grabbing. - `.jpg .png` etc.

You just need to grab the image source from somewhere.

Example (using `$_GET`):

```
<?php

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='GET'){
$img_src=$_GET['img_src']
}

echo "<img src='/images/test/" . $img_src . "' alt='img'>";

?>
```

Comment: You use `"` because you can use simple `echo "<img src='/images/test/{ $img_src}' alt='img'>";`

Answer (score 0):

1. Upload the image in your media files
2. Get the url/path of the uploaded image
3. Do this!

```
$image='<img src="https://www.yoursite.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/02/dope.png"/>';
echo $image;
```